# Year in Nullable DateTime

Tags: c#, .net

How can I calculate year in a `nullable` date?

```
partial void AgeAtDiagnosis_Compute(ref int result)
{
    // Set result to the desired field value
    result = DateofDiagnosis.Year - DateofBirth.Year;
    if (DateofBirth > DateofDiagnosis.AddYears(-result))
    {
      result--;
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Year' and no 
 extension method 'Year' accepting a first argument of 
 type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using 
 directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Does it work with real DateTime? If so can't you use the non null value. Seems like if it's null the year calculation is not needed anyway?

Comment: You should have searched google https://www.google.co.in/search?q=nullable+datetime+in+c%23

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Replace `DateofDiagnosis.Year` with `DateofDiagnosis.Value.Year`

And check the `DateofDiagnosis.HasValue` to assert that it is not null first.

I would write the code like this:

```
private bool TryCalculateAgeAtDiagnosis( DateTime? dateOfDiagnosis, 
                                         DateTime? dateOfBirth, 
                                         out int ageInYears)
{
    if (!dateOfDiagnosis.HasValue || !dateOfBirth.HasValue)
    {
        ageInYears = default;
        return false;
    }

    ageInYears = dateOfDiagnosis.Value.Year - dateOfBirth.Value.Year;

    if (dateOfBirth > dateOfDiagnosis.Value.AddYears(-ageInYears))
    {
        ageInYears--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First check if it has a `Value`:

```
if (date.HasValue == true)
{
    //date.Value.Year;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `nullableDateTime.Value.Year`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code may look like this,

```
partial void AgeAtDiagnosis_Compute(ref int result)
        {
            if(DateofDiagnosis.HasValue && DateofBirth.HasValue)
            {
                // Set result to the desired field value
                result = DateofDiagnosis.Value.Year - DateofBirth.Value.Year;
                if (DateofBirth > DateofDiagnosis.Value.AddYears(-result))
                {
                  result--;
                }
            }
        }
```